# Equivalent to `.push()` for object instead of array

Tags: object

I originally had an array of data with sub-arrays, however I need to make this an object instead.

My final data should look something like:

```
var invalidFields = {
    0: {
        lastName: <input type="text" ... />,
        city: <input type="text" ... />,
        ...
    }
    2: {
        lastName: <input type="text" ... />,
        city: <input type="text" ... />,
        ...
    }
}
```

Please note, above, that there is no key `1`.

I am having trouble adding the data to the object. I am iterating over an existing array and finding matches that are invalid, and then want to "push" them to a new object.

For example the key for the top-level multi-dimension e.g `0` or `2` is stored as `passengerIndex` in my code but I cannot work out how to add it.

I am initialising with `invalidFields = {}`

I have tried. `invalidFields[passengerIndex]`

I have also tried `invalidFields.passengerIndex`

And `invalidFields = invalidFields[passengerIndex]`

But none work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are working with Javascript

You will need to find another variable-name, maybe add an underscore before the number since a variable cannot start with a number
see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types

> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($)

or maybe you could use a Map https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map